# Sendgrid giving two response codes...Unusual

Tags: php, http-headers, sendgrid

I am trying to send mail through sendgrid API but what i see unusual is its giving me two response codes instead of one. And it does not send mail. Why??

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue"
  [1]=>
  string(1) ""
  [2]=>
  string(25) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "Server: nginx"
  [4]=>
  string(36) "Date: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 22:08:03 GMT"
  [5]=>
  string(31) "Content-Type: application/json"
  [6]=>
  string(20) "Content-Length: 507"
  [7]=>
  string(23) "Connection: keep-alive"
  [8]=>
  string(22) "X-Frame-Options: DENY"
  [9]=>
  string(58) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io"
  [10]=>
  string(35) "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST"
  [11]=>
  string(87) "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl"
  [12]=>
  string(28) "Access-Control-Max-Age: 600"
  [13]=>
  string(75) "X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html"
  [14]=>
  string(1) ""
  [15]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I have downloaded the sendgrid code and wrote a wrapper class `Mailer` to use sendgrid

I am trying to achieve like this.

```
        $template = APP_PATH."/application/views/layouts/mails/NewEmployee.html";
        $mail_body = file_get_contents($template);
        $formated_mail_body = str_replace(
            ["{{name}}", "{{email}}", "{{password}}"], [$name, $email, $password], $mail_body);
        $from = [
            "name" => "XYZ company",
            "email" => "hr@xyz.com"
        ];
        $to = [
            ["name" => $name, "email" => $email]
        ];
        $subject = "Welcome on Board, Xyz Co.";
        $sendgrid_mailer = new Mailer();
        $sendgrid_mailer->addSender($from);
        $sendgrid_mailer->addRecipient($to);
        $sendgrid_mailer->addSubject($subject);
        $sendgrid_mailer->addBodyContent($formated_mail_body);
        $sendgrid_mailer->addReplyTo($from);
        $response = $sendgrid_mailer->send();
        var_dump($response);
```

Comment: And what is your question? ;)

Comment: The question is why ?? why two response codes..

Comment: Check the meaning of the code 100: "The client SHOULD continue with its request. This interim response is used to inform the client that the initial part of the request has been received and has not yet been rejected by the server. [...]", https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html